# How to specify the target URL path in HTTP Proxy authentication

Tags: java, authentication, proxy

I need to get the API response contents from an API server to my local server, via a proxy authentication. The API request will be like:

```
http://api.example.com/nav_page/head?locale=in&pointer=old&cont=/resque/&scope=old&release=new




import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnRoutePNames;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;


public class ClientProxyAuthentication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope("proxy.example.com", 8080),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("Domain\user", "pass"));

            HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("api.example.com", 80, "http");
            HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.example.com", 8080);

            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/");

            System.out.println("executing request: " + httpget.getRequestLine());
            System.out.println("via proxy: " + proxy);
            System.out.println("to target: " + targetHost);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(targetHost, httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
            Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
            for (int i = 0; i<headers.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(headers[i]);
            }
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);

        } finally {
            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
            // shut down the connection manager to ensure
            // immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, if target URL is specified as api.example.com, The authentication succeeds and getting the resource (but there is no resource in base dir, hence nothing useful received). But to get correct response, I need to provide the navigation path inside that host.

Hence if i append the path like

```
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("api.example.com/nav_page/head?locale=in&pointer=old&cont=/resque/&scope=old&release=new", 80, "http");
```

I am getting some error response, but not correct one.

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Response content length: 442
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1>
<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

I am able to get the response, if i hit URL directly in browser.

May i know how to send the request for the navigation path?

Comment: In the above case, if the content is in base dir of target URL, I'm getting it. But as i dont have any control on that server, I cant request to move content to base dir

Comment: Finally i found out. need to specify in HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/nav_page/head?locale=in&pointer=old&cont=/resque/&scope=old&release=new"); parameter